# Как в Django вывести кастомизированый QuerySet?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

У менять есть модель

```
class MoneyOperation(models.Model):
money_type = models.ForeignKey(MoneyTypeOperation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
sum = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='money_get')
date = models.DateField(null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

При закрытии смены туда записывается на каждого работника по две суммы(одна оклад, вторая бонус к окладу) и имеет следующий вид

```
 {
    "id": 221,
    "employee_id": "Тест1",
    "sum": 2500,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
},
{
    "id": 222,
    "employee_id": "Тест1",
    "sum": 1866,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
},
{
    "id": 223,
    "employee_id": "Тест2",
    "sum": 2500,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
},
{
    "id": 224,
    "employee_id": "Тест2",
    "sum": 1866,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
},
```

Как мне получить объединенный вариант на каждого работника? Например

```
"date": "2023-04-13",
"workers":[
    {
    "id": 221,
    "employee_id": "Тест1",
    "sum": 2500,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
},
{
    "id": 222,
    "employee_id": "Тест1",
    "sum": 1866,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
}],
[{
    "id": 223,
    "employee_id": "Тест2",
    "sum": 2500,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
},
{
    "id": 224,
    "employee_id": "Тест2",
    "sum": 1866,
    "date": "2023-04-13",
    "description": "",
    "money_type": "Смена"
}],
```

Так же есть сейчас такой вьюсет через который и планирую это кастомизировать

```
class MoneyOperationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = MoneyOperation.objects.all()
    date = self.request.query_params.get('date')

    if date:
        queryset = queryset.filter(date=date)
        for el in queryset:
            print(el.id)
    return queryset
serializer_class = MoneyOperationsSerializer
```